# Android 2.2 SDK - PhotoCapture example not working

Tags: android, mobile, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I'm integrating exact code from here: http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/

How the activity should work:  click "button" -> go to default camera.  Take photo.  "Retake" button works, "cancel" button works (brings back to "button" layout), but the "ok" button doesn't work (and then the image should appear above the "button" in the previous layout). Does this have something to do with how it's saving image to SD card?  I can't figure it out!  Also, I'm testing this app on a device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work:

```
package com.android.xxx;

import java.io.File;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Window;

public class CameraView extends MenusHolder {

    protected String _path;
    protected boolean _taken;

    protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_event_view);

        File imageDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder/");
        imageDirectory.mkdirs();

        _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder/temporary_holder.jpg"; 

        startCameraActivity();

    }

    protected void startCameraActivity() {

        File file = new File(_path);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch(resultCode) {

            case 0:
                finish();
                break;

            case -1:
                onPhotoTaken();
                break;

        }

    }

    protected void onPhotoTaken() {

        _taken = true;
        finish();
        Intent newView1 = new Intent(CameraView.this, CreateEventView.class);
        CameraView.this.startActivity(newView1);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        outState.putBoolean(CameraView.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken);  

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(CameraView.PHOTO_TAKEN)) {

            onPhotoTaken();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: One additional thing needed is to include <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> in your manifest so you can create a new directory.